# How can I make prettier put HTML/JSX attributes on the same line up to a specific length?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsx, prettier, prettier-vscode

prettier do this auto newline

```
<TextField
  name="message"
  variant="outlined"
  label="Message"
  fullWidth
  value={postData.message}
  onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, message: e.target.value })}
/>
```

what, i want like this
can prettier do this?

```
<TextField
  name="message" variant="outlined" label="Message" fullWidth value={postData.message}
  onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, message: e.target.value })}
/>
```

Comment: Probably not. The point of prettier is that it's not got that many options to configure, to just end those endless debates. Besides, your second code block is not very readable.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get is

- disabling [`singleAttributePerLine: <bool>`](https://singleAttributePerLine:%20%3Cbool%3E)
- and set a very large [`printWidth: <int>`](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options#print-width).

That way everything will be placed in one line. Anything that exceeds these requirements is not configurable with Prettier alone.